# "DeltaFIFO Pop Process" - Reason:slow event handlers blocking the queue on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, event-handling, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

**CONTEXT:**

I accidently deleted the namespace where Cert-manager runs. After redeploying (static manifest) Cert-manager's webhook was failing to generate initial serving certificate but gladly I had a backup of the secret and I restored them(cert-manager-webhook-ca & cert-manager-webhook-tls).

Now webhook pod is working with no issues. However:

**PROBLEM:**

Cert-manager's pod was working fine with no errors in the logs but after fixing the webhook, in the Cert-manager's pod logs I noticed these messages (repeatedly with different IDs) here's an example of one of the logs messages:

```
Trace[1788197141]: "DeltaFIFO Pop Process" ID:namespace/model-secrets,Depth:189,Reason:slow event handlers blocking the queue
```

I have also created an ingress in a different namespace and deleted it but i'd still see this in the certmanager's logs:

```
ingress 'microservices/test-ingress' in work queue no longer exists
```

**ATTEMPTS:**

I increased the number of replicas in the Cert-manager Deployment from 1 to 2 replicas.

I increased the resources request and limits in the Cert-manager Deployment.

I created a ConfigMap and specified:

```
deltafifo-queue-history-size: "1056"
```

**Environment:**

Cert-manager : v1.10.0

Kubernetes: 1.21.14-gke.4300

Does anyone know how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm writing an operator which stores TLS secrets generated by cert-manager to AWS ASM. If I monitor a single namespace there are no problems. If I monitor all namespaces, though, I get the `DeltaFIFO Pop process` information log entry. Perhaps it's just nothing more than information, but it causes me to think something is wrong. I've tried everything in my code to overcome this but nothing works (including multi-threaded go routines).

Comment: Hi, I didn't implement a specific solution. I increased the CPU requests/limits and for the flag deltafifo-queue-history-size: "1056" is actually wrong so ignore this. 
Basically, Certmanager was working normally regardless of the messages so I just ignored it and the log msg was then gone.

Comment: I figured out what was causing my problem. When I went through my code more closely, I was duplicating API calls in the same operation thereby causing slow-down for the `DeltaFIFO Pop`. For me, my problem was my code.